# Python Credit Card Check Function not running correctly

Tags: python

Trying to implement a program in Python that can check if the input is a valid credit card and display the credit card type(VISA/MASTERCARD/AMEX). For 2 values it's displaying incorrectly and for 2 days I have no ideas how to fix it ?

Output received:( last 2 are incorect 4111111111111113 and 4222222222223) I guess is something related with the check_last_digit function ....

```
identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
:) identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
:) identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
:) identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD
:) identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA
:) identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA
:) identifies 4222222222222 as VISA
:) identifies 1234567890 as INVALID
:) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID
:) identifies 4062901840 as INVALID
:) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID
:( **identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID**
    **expected "INVALID\n", not "VISA\n\n"**
:( **identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID**
    **expected "INVALID\n", not "VISA\n\n**
```

My Code:

```
#function to find out the sum of every other numbers from the input card
def odd_sum(num):
    num = list(str(num))
    my_list_digits = [int(item) * 2 for item in num][::2]
    total_odd = 0
    for number in my_list_digits:
        if number > 9:
            first_digit = number // 10
            second_digit = number % 10
            total_odd += first_digit + second_digit

        else:
            total_odd += number
    return total_odd


# function to find out the sum of the other remaining numbers
def even_sum(num):
    num = list(str(num))
    del num[::2]
    my_list_digits1 = [int(item) for item in num]
    total_even = 0
    for item in my_list_digits1:
        total_even += item
    return total_even


# function to check the lenght of the input card
def check_length(num):
    num = str(num)
    num_length = len(num)
    if 13 <= num_length <= 16:
        return True
    else:
        print("INVALID")

# function to check the last digit of the sum ( even and odd)
def check_last_digit(num):
    odd = odd_sum(num)
    even = even_sum(num)
    if (odd + even) % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# function to determine the type of card that was provided
def card_type(card_num):
    card_num = str(card_num)
    AMEX = ["34", "37"]
    MASTERCARD = ["51", "52", "53", "54", "55"]
    VISA = ["4"]
    if (card_num[0:2]) in AMEX:
        print("AMEX")
    elif (card_num[0:2]) in MASTERCARD:
        print("MASTERCARD")
    elif (card_num[0]) == VISA[0]:
        print("VISA\n")
    else:
        print("INVALID")



# main program to run all the above created functions
def main():
    #get input from user
    card_num = int(input("CARD: "))
    #check if the bellow 2 functions are True and if so, run the card type function so we can see what type of card was usde(visa, mastercard,amex)
    if check_length(card_num):
        card_type(card_num)
    else:
        if check_last_digit(card_num):
            card_type(card_num)



main()
```

Comment: Note: In your `check_length` you're not returning a value in your else statement. You should add `return False` behind `print("INVALID")`.

Comment: @Jakob, even with this change it doesn't change the status of the 2 inputs..

Comment: I know, but you should still do it to avoid problems in the future and to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your main function

```py
#check if the bellow 2 functions are True and if so, run the card type function so we can see what type of card was usde(visa, mastercard,amex)
if check_length(card_num):
    card_type(card_num)
else:
    if check_last_digit(card_num):
        card_type(card_num)
```

is supposed to check that both `check_length` and `check_last_digit` are passed. However, in your code, if `check_length` returns `True`, then the second check is not ran. You need to change your code to make sure that both test are run:

```py
def main():
    #get input from user
    card_num = int(input("CARD: "))
    #check if the bellow 2 functions are True and if so, run the card type function so we can see what type of card was usde(visa, mastercard,amex)
    if check_length(card_num) and check_last_digit(card_num):
        card_type(card_num)
    else:
        print("INVALID")
```

*Edit*:

There are two other errors in your implementation of the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).
The `odd_sum` function is supposed to sum every other digit, starting from the **right-most** one, and skipping one, but your implementation sums the wrong digits if the number of digits of the input number is odd. To correct for that, you should, for instance, reverse the list first:

```py
l = [int(item) * 2 for item in num[::-1]]
```

then, remove the first digit (the rightmost one)

```py
l = l[1:]
```

and finally, take every other digit:

```py
my_list_digits = l[::2]
```

Then, there's a similar error in `even_sum`, you should also consider reversing the list, to make sure to consider the correct digits:

```py
my_list_digits1 = [int(item) for item in num[::-1]]
return sum(my_list_digits1)
```

Lastly, as Jakob mentioned, you should return `False` instead of `"INVALID"` in your `check_length` function.

As a refactoring tip, if you see yourself writing

```py
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

then you can refactor that in the cleaner:

```py
return condition
```

So for instance:

```py
def check_last_digit(num):
    odd = odd_sum(num)
    even = even_sum(num)
    return (odd + even) % 10 == 0:
```

Comment: after edit :( identifies 4222222222222 as VISA
    expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n":( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"
:( identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"

Comment: Thank you @Florent MONIN. Will try to modify it and will revert back. I've scratch my head for 2 days but couldn't figure it out

Comment: No problem, you're welcome! I hope this helped you fix your issue! If so, don't hesitate to accept my answer